# php array needed

Tags: php, arrays

hi all i need a `snippet` i know can do it with a bit of coding

but i need a snippet

i want an array of say `choosable` length like `getArray(50)` gives me a array of size 50

like we declare na ?

`array[50]` in other languages

and i want to fill it with some random data.

I want some real cool methods!

Like this

```
array(
  0=>"sds"
  1=>"bds"
....

n=>"mds"
);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you need?

Comment: i want an array of specific length which may vary filled with junk data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of a specific length, that is pre-filled with a given value, using the `array_fill()` function. I don't think that there is an in-built function that will generate arrays with random contents, though.

```
$myArray = array_fill(0, 50, null);
```

What form exactly do you want the array elements to take? You want them to be a lowercase letter frollowed by `"ds"`?

```
$myArraySize = 50;
$myArray = array_fill(0, $myArraySize, '_ds');
for ($i=0; $i<$myArraySize; $i++) {
    $myArray[$i][0] = chr(mt_rand(97, 122));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be used to get array's of specific length filled with 24 character long string. Use it according to your use.

```
<?php
function generate_array($num)
{
    $input = array();

    $result = array_pad($input, $num, 0);
    foreach($result as $key=>$val)
    {
        $result[$key] = gen_rand_str_24();
    }
    return $result;
}

function gen_rand_str_24()
{
     return pack('N6', mt_rand(), mt_rand(), mt_rand(), mt_rand(), mt_rand(), mt_rand());
}

$result = generate_array(5);
print_r($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = "a";
$arr[] = "b";
```

Or similar:

```
$arr = array( 0 =>  "a",
              1 =>     "b");
```

You don't need to set a length before filling it in PHP.

Comment: i want an array of specific length which may vary filled with junk data

Comment: when you post an answer please check the question